Error when creating standalone directive library and usin it in local
I am building a library and have this directive:
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Output, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { rutClean, rutFormat } from './rut-utils';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formatRut]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class RutDirective {
  @Output() public rutChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target'])
  public onFocus(htmlInputElement: HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(1);
    htmlInputElement.value = rutClean(htmlInputElement.value);
  }

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target'])
  public onBlur(htmlInputElement: HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(2);
    htmlInputElement.value = rutFormat(htmlInputElement.value) || '';
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
  public onChange(htmlInputElement: HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(3);
    this.rutChange.emit(rutClean(htmlInputElement.value));
  }
}

I build the library and install it in a new Angular 18 project.
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RutTestDirective } from '../directives/test.directive';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RutDirective } from 'ngx-test-library';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-library',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './input-library.component.html',
  styleUrl: './input-library.component.scss',
  imports: [RutPipe, RutDirective, FormsModule],
})
export class InputLibraryComponent {
  someValue: string = '';
}

Here is the HTML template:
<h1>DIRECTIVES</h1>
<div>
  <input formatRut [(ngModel)]="someValue" />
</div>

When I open in the browser, I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '11')
    at ɵɵlistener (core.mjs:25618:34)
    at Object.RutDirective_HostBindings [as hostBindings] (rut.directive.ts:8:26)
    at invokeHostBindingsInCreationMode (core.mjs:12436:9)
    at invokeDirectivesHostBindings (core.mjs:12420:9)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:11821:5)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:23561:5)
    at InputLibraryComponent_Template (input-library.component.html:12:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11785:5)
    at renderView (core.mjs:12947:7)
    at renderComponent (core.mjs:12893:3)

However, if I copy the directive code from the library directly into the project, it works perfectly. So, I think this might be a problem with the tsconfig file. The library was generated with the Angular 18 CLI, and I haven't modified the tsconfig file.
Note: This happens with the directive, but when I create a pipe, I don't have any problems.
I tried to modify the directive decorator with host, so I wouldn't need to use @HostListener, but I still get the same error.
@Directive({
  selector: '[formatRut]',
  host: {
    '(blur)': 'onBlur($event)',
    '(focus)': 'onFocus($event)',
    '(input)': 'onChange($event)',
  },
})


Could you share a working example on stackblitz, or a github repo where the issue happens?

No, its a local library
